# Cross-site duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What should be done with cross-site duplicate questions?

There is this question about a certain XNA issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498635/resize-game-windows-without-freezing-and-stretching

…And the answer to that can be found in this question: [How do I prevent XNA from pausing Updates while the window is being resized/moved?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51376/how-do-i-prevent-xna-from-pausing-updates-while-the-window-is-being-resized-move)

But they're on different SE sites! What to do?

Comment: In *most cases* if a question is on topic on one site the it will be off topic on other site. So just flag/close it as off topic.

Comment: I don't think this is one of those cases though.

Comment: Are the _questions_ exact duplicates? Are the a cross post? No. They are also both on topic for the sites they are on. If you want, post a _comment_ linking to the answer on the other site.